# Select any column as name as variable

Tags: sql-server

I want in select statement using a column as somename and using in where. (SQL Server)

I've used in SyBase:

```
SELECT
  'teste' as col1
  from sometable
  where col1 = 'teste'
```

Works!

In MySql:

```
SELECT
  @col1:= 'teste'
  from sometable
  where @col1 = 'teste'
```

Works!

I need equivalent in SqlServer, but show erro that col1 doesn't exists.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you sure it's not supposed to be `SET @variable= ...` ? Also, where is the ending semicolon `;`?

Comment: This is not possible directly, because chronologically, WHERE happens before SELECT, which always is the last step in the execution chain. you can achieve this using CTE.

Comment: @frakman1, it´s not set variable that I need..... I want an equivalent in SyBase, that you can define column alias and use everywhere in statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a subquery or a CTE (which is just a Syntactic sugar of subquery).

I am not sure of the use of '@variable:=' in Sybase so I am just ignoring it based on the conversation in comments.

Subquery:

```
SELECT
        col1
    FROM (
        SELECT
            'teste' AS col1
        --,st.*
        FROM sometable AS st
    ) s
    WHERE col1 = 'teste'
```

CTE:

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT
        'teste' AS col1
        --,st.*
    FROM sometable AS st
)
SELECT
        col1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE col1 = 'teste'
```